Courant nodal domain theorem for Riesz potential operator
Let $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^N$ be a bounded open set and $N\geq 2$. Let $0<\alpha<N$.
The Riesz potential operator on $L^2(\Omega)$ is defined by
\begin{equation*}
    R_{\alpha,\Omega}(u)(x):=\int_\Omega \frac{u(y)}{|x-y|^{N-\alpha}}dy 
\end{equation*}
The eigenvalues and the corresponding eigenfunctions satisfy the following equations:
\begin{equation*}
     \int_\Omega \int_\Omega \frac{u_n(x)\phi(y)}{|x-y|^{N-\alpha}}dxdy=\lambda_n \int_\Omega u_n(x)\phi(x)dx, \forall \phi\in L^2(\Omega)
\end{equation*}
Can we show that number of nodal domains is finite for
eigenfunctions?
Atleast, is it possible to show that number of
nodal domains is finite for second eigenfunction?
Or is it possible to show that, for radial eigenfunctions number of nodal domains is finite?
The second eigenvalue has the following variational characterization:
\begin{equation*}\label{second}
\lambda_2=\max \left\{ \int_\Omega \int_\Omega \frac{u(x)u(y)}{|x-y|^{N-\alpha}}dxdy:u\in L^2(\Omega),u\perp u_1,\|u\|_{L^2(\Omega)}=1\right\}.
\end{equation*}

It is encouraged to only ask one question per post.

what is a nodal domain?

Have you looked at the proof of Courant's nodal domain theorem? It would be helpful to know how that proof fails when the Laplacian is replaced by the Riesz operator
